# Unable to run Java main class though windows commandline

Tags: java, javac

I have an external jar and I have written 2 classes named 'TestConnector.java' and 'APIExampleUsageTestData.java' and I have placed these 2 files under default package.

I have placed all the 3 artifacts -> externalConnector.jar, TestConnector.java and APIExampleUsageTestData.java into a folder named 'temp'.

I have opened commandline in the temp folder context and compiled the class files with below command and it executed without any errors:

```
javac -cp "externalConnector.jar" *.java
```

I can see that there are 2 class files present in the tem folder.

There is a main method in the APIExampleUsageTestData.class and I'm trying to call that class with the below command, but, is failing

When running the below command in 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\0.15429262750877082' folder context

```
java -cp "externalConnector.jar" APIExampleUsageTestData
```

I'm getting error `Error: Could not find or load main class APIExampleUsageTestData`

When I trying to run the command, without any class path entry to check what error it is throwing:

```
java APIExampleUsageTestData
```

It throws error: `Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/external/connector/CustomException`

It is a Windows Operating System. Could you please let me know how to run the program successfully?

Answer (score 2):

You need both the current directory *and* the jar file to be on the classpath. So you want (Linux / Mac):

```sh
java -cp .:externalConnector.jar APIExampleUsageTestData
```

Or (Windows)

```sh
java -cp .;externalConnector.jar APIExampleUsageTestData
```